# Isssues forwarding port / Nat on openbsd

Tags: openbsd, router, pf

I am unable to make port 80 available on the WAN and I am not sure why.

My setup is just my home network acting as the wan and my ‘lab’ as the lan. Wan 192.168.0.0/24 and lan is 192.168.5.0/24. Router wan interface is 192.168.0.113 and the lan interface is 192.168.5.1. The web server is at 192.168.5.17 and I am trying to forward port 80 on 192.168.0.133. to make it available on the wan. I put the current version of the rules and the pf logs below. It looks to me like it is just not redirecting the traffic and I do not know why. Any help is appreciated, if you need more info I would be happy to provide it. Thanks!

Oh and the ssh rule works fine I guess b/c it just uses the wan interface and doesn’t redirect to another machine.

Also also I have tried the last rule with and without port 80 rdr-to 192.168.5.17 and I get the same error

I tried to include the pflog info but stack exchange said it was spam...

```
#no need to run rules on the loop back int
set skip on lo

#macro to set the external int to em0
ext_if = "em0"

#macro to set the internal int to the other eth int
int_if = "re0"

#macro for the webserver
web_server = "192.168.5.17"

#making table for people that we want to block
table <badguys> persist file "/etc/badguys"
block quick from <badguys>

#naming specific trusted IPs
trusted = "{ 192.168.0.155 }"

#blocking all inbound and outbound ip6 traffic
block inet6

#default policy, remember pf is a last match application unless you use quick
block all

#this is for passing and taging all internal traffic
pass in on $int_if tag ALLOWED

#perform NAT
match out on $ext_if inet from ($int_if:network) to any nat-to ($ext_if)

#pass out all of the packets that were tagged
pass out on $ext_if tagged ALLOWED

#allows traffic out from the host
pass out from { ($ext_if),$int_if }

#rule to let in ssh
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp from {192.168.0.0/24 $trusted} to {192.168.0.113} port 22 flags S/SA keep state \
                       (max-src-conn 5, max-src-conn-rate 5/5, \
                                  overload <badguys> flush global)

#trying to forward http

pass log on $int_if from 192.168.5.17 to any binat-to 192.168.0.113
pass in log on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 192.168.0.113 port 80 rdr-to 192.168.5.17
```

Comment: Jul 24 21:55:12.985868 rule 9/(match) match in on em0: 192.168.0.155.47262 > 192.168.0.113.80: S 570634302:570634302(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 2569937712 0,nop,wscale 7> (DF)
Jul 24 21:55:46.266511 rule 9/(match) match in on em0: 192.168.0.155.47262 > 192.168.0.113.80: S 570634302:570634302(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 2569970992 0,nop,wscale 7> (DF)

Comment: There we go, that is the log info

Comment: I do not think the binat-to rule is really required. What you need is to just redirect http from any to the 0.133:80 to the 5.17:80 which  can be expressed by modifying the rdr-to rule (last one). Give it a try!

Comment: Jul 25 14:40:12.849459 rule 9/(match) pass in on em0: 192.168.0.155.57106 > 192.168.0.113.80: S 1652474580:1652474580(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 2587618483 0,nop,wscale 7> (DF)

Comment: I changed the rule to:
pass in log on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 192.168.0.113 port 80 rdr-to 192.168.5.17

and got the log entry above but no website. Also thanks for the help!

Comment: try removing the binato rule

Comment: Ok now the full rule reads:
#trying to forward http
pass in log on $ext_if proto tcp from any to 192.168.0.113 port 80 rdr-to 192.168.5.17

Took the binat completely out

Comment: Reloaded the rules and am getting:
Jul 25 16:31:34.264179 rule 9/(match) pass in on em0: 192.168.0.155.57328 > 192.168.0.113.80: S 2369092205:2369092205(0) win 64240 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 2589394885 0,nop,wscale 7> (DF)

Comment: Nginx access log:
192.168.5.18 - - [24/Jul/2022:22:30:26 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 125 "http://192.168.5.17/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"

So nothing has accessed it today

Comment: Have you enabled  ip forwarding on the gateway? A linux/bsd system will not forward packets across interfaces unless you explicitly enabled it, and this have nothing to do with pf. Have a look at https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/nat.html#ipfwd  to enable.

Comment: Yes, my sysctl.conf has:
net.inet.ip.forwarding=1

Comment: I've requested that your question be moved to superuser, serverfault or networkengineering forums for more attention. You may post it there if not done by moderators.

Comment: Ok cool, I am not sure how to do that but really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `binat` rule.

```
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to $(ext_if) port 80 rdr-to 192.168.5.17
pass out on $int_if proto tcp to 192.168.5.17 port 80
```

should suffice.  Note that this last rule is not covered by

```
pass out from { ($ext_if),$int_if }
```

because the redirected package does not come from `$ext_if`'s IP address nor from the `$int_if`.

Since you are more or less in control of what happens on the host, adding a simple `pass out` rule (i.e. filtering only incoming traffic both on WAN and LAN) and getting rid of all other `pass out ...` rules might make things simpler, in general.

Using `tcpdump` on both external and internal interfaces to see whether the packages (and their replies) are actually forwarded and redirected/NATed might help.  I also recommend doing the same on the webserver.

Also, lookout for routing issues. Make sure that the webserver knows where to send its replies to.  In your example, if it knows that 192.168.5.1 is the gateway for packets destined to 192.168.0.0/24 (or even its default gateway).

Comment: That was it! I will have to remember that I can use tcp dump and do a packet capture rather than just reading the PF logs with it. Thanks!

Comment: @zé-loff, I am curious about why the second rule is necessary. Does not pf create state allowing reverse way from the first one across the entire device, not limited to the $ext-if ?

Comment: @BrahimGaabab yes, it does, but its a different interface, you have to explicitly allow it to go out on `$int_if`. The created states make it unnecessary to create `pass out` rules for the replies (i.e. out of `$ext_if` back to the client, and in `$int_if` from the server), but not for establishing the connections on both `_if`s.

Comment: Thank you @zé-loff. I understand. Filtering in pf happens at interfaces rather on chains as in netfilter!